# Apache Airflow - generating tasks dynamically based on the user input parameters (provided via 'Trigger DAG w/config' button)

Tags: airflow

I have the following use case with airflow 2.6.3 (it's my first dag, so I am aware of my limited experience):

1. I have some "components" which are simply application processes that I need to start or stop in certain order, e.g. 'component1' which is a java batch with its own command to start/stop on remote machine, 'component2' is a Tomcat, 'component3' is a Apache webserver, etc...
2. User can select which components to trigger (any set is valid, e.g. only 'component2' or 'component1' and 'component3', etc.). In general, there is going to be a few tens of components

The approach I tried to implement (if there are better ideas, I am open to hear) is to have the input in YAML file, something like:

```
components:
 -
  name: "component1"
  start_cmd = "${HOME}/app/startup.sh
  stop_cmd = "${HOME}/app/shutdown.sh
  remote_user = "usr1"
  remote_host = "myhost1"
  run_after: 
   - component2
   - component3
#more components after that
```

3. The first task of my dag will be (after user triggers it with 'Trigger dag w/config' button) generating config form with switches for each component, so user selects what to run, something like:

```
  for component in config_file['components']:
     component_name = component['name']    
     params[component_name] = Param(
     False,
     title = component_name,
     type = "boolean"
     )
```

Later, I read user's input (which will be stored in params object) and construct the right order of run based on run_after YAML field (which actually defines the order of my dag's tasks). Then  I generate dynamically the tasks based on SSHOperator and feel happy.

However, I am a kind of stuck because I realized that the user's inputs are known only during (and after) the run of my first task and I can't generate the subsequent tasks which is done as part of authoring when tasks context is not available. I considered to use Dynamic Mapping but if I have many tens of components the dag will appear in the Graph View with tens of "hidden" individual tasks (one per each component) which makes it practically impossible to use and troubleshoot.
So, what would be the best approach to implement such workflow?

Comment: You can share data between tasks using [xcoms](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/core-concepts/xcoms.html)

Comment: using xcom seems to be not an option as per my understanding xcom pushed in my first task still not be available out of task context, so how can it help me to generate tasks and their dependencies based on the xcom ?

Comment: looks like you need to create a few specific DAGs with `None` _scheduler interval_ and run it using [API](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/stable-rest-api-ref.html#operation/post_dag_run). I don't see the whole picture. Maybe you'll help [teardown](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/howto/setup-and-teardown.html), [TaskGroups](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/core-concepts/dags.html#taskgroups) or [SubDags](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/core-concepts/dags.html#subdags)

Comment: Would you add some more details? Do you want to see a graph with tasks? Or do you just need the ability to run some chains? Do you have a certain number of chains? Сan the graph contain tasks that run in parallel? I mean the question includes too many nuances.